# Guice : Injection and the compiler

Tags: methods, compilation, arguments, guice

If I declare a method :

public Car makeCar(@Named("carClassName") String carClassName){
    //...
}

It seems that the compiler (eclipse) is unhappy (i.e. it won't let me call the class with no arguments).

How can I inject these parameters when I call this method , dynamically ?  Is there a way to inject a call to a method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: insert carClassName in the caller,

```
class Whatever {
   private @Named("carClassName") String carClassName);
   public void dosomething() {
      ...
      Cat cat = makeCar(carclassName);
      ...
   }
}
```

Solution 2: use a factory,

```
class CarFactory {      
  private @Named("carClassName") String carClassName);
  public Car create() {
     return makeCar(carClassName);
  }
}
```

and inject it where needed.

Comment: In other words : Guice doesn't effect compile time syntax rules - rather, it changes values of items at runtime..... Funny how sometimes I forget this .  Thanks for the reminder